# Why isn't my Quick Look generator being used by Finder?

Tags: finder, quicklook

I've created a `QuickLookMsgPack.qlgenerator`, which is placed in `~/Library/QuickLook/QuickLookMsgPack.qlgenerator`.

`qlmanage` find it:

```
$ qlmanage -m plugins | grep QuickLookMsgPack
  se.xyz.msgpack -> ~/Library/QuickLook/QuickLookMsgPack.qlgenerator (1.0)
```

I can even debug it using:

```
qlmanage -p -c se.xyz.msgpack ~/Downloads/path/2023-03-16_15-13-47.912-write.msg
```

However, Finder never uses my generator, it just show the generic "Quick Look". Here's how it looks in Finder:

[image]

Here's the relevant parts of my Info.plist:

```
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
            <array>
                <string>public.data</string>
            </array>
            <key>UTTypeDescription</key>
            <string>Message pack document</string>
            <key>UTTypeIconFile</key>
            <string>public.text.icns</string>
            <key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>
            <string>se.xyz.msgpack</string>
            <key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>
            <dict>
                <key>public.filename-extension</key>
                <array>
                    <string>msg</string>
                    <string>pack</string>
                </array>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>QLGenerator</string>
            <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
            <array>
                <string>se.xyz.msgpack</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
```

Comment: Not sure removing the information about this being a self-developed generator helps to make this on-topic. But as seen in the screenshot, FInder doesn't know about .msg at all.

Comment: But there's an issue with how Finder behaves and I want to figure out that's wrong.. I mean, it could even be the case that this hasn't to do with the generator? Or it could. But by closing it as off topic you basically say it's all an issue with the generator.

Comment: The question was written that way but maybe I wasn't reading  carefully enough :-). Rolled back the edit (because the plist might help) and reopened.